# group member unable to write to a group-writable file with reiserfs and extended ACLs

Tags: linux, files, permissions, acl, reiserfs

Users `vi` and `rust` share group `rust` and want to use some file in shared manner.

```
rust$ ls -l myfile 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vi rust 0 May 30 03:48 myfile
rust$ stat myfile  | grep Gid
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/      vi)   Gid: ( 1057/    rust)
rust$ id
uid=1048(rust) gid=1057(rust) groups=1057(rust),...

rust$ cat myfile
rust$ touch myfile 
touch: cannot touch ‘myfile’: Permission denied
rust $ dd of=myfile 
dd: failed to open ‘myfile’: Permission denied

vi$ id
uid=1000(vi) gid=1000(vi) groups=1000(vi),{many unrelated groups skipped},1057(rust),{many unrelated groups skipped}
vi$ touch myfile
vi$
```

Only "vi" user has write access to the file despite of g+w.

```
root# chown rust myfile
rust$ ls -l myfile 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rust rust 0 May 30 03:51 myfile
vi$ touch myfile
rust$ chmod g-w myfile
vi$ touch myfile 
touch: cannot touch ‘myfile’: Permission denied
```

`vi` can or can't write to `rust`'s file depending on g+w bit, as excepted.

Why group-writable bit works only in one direction?

The file remains unavailable even in `a+w` mode. Third user can write to the file with `a+w` although...

`getfacl myfile` returns `Invalid argument`.

The file is on local reiserfs.

`id vi` and `id rust` matches `id` in respective users' shells up to order of unrelated groups.

---

One more experiment:

```
vi$ chmod a+w myfile
vi$ stat myfile
  File: ‘myfile’
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: fb02h/64258d    Inode: 12618147    Links: 1
Access: (0666/-rw-rw-rw-)  Uid: ( 1000/      vi)   Gid: ( 1057/    rust)
Access: 2016-05-30 18:49:20.000000000 +0300
Modify: 2016-05-30 20:48:23.000000000 +0300
Change: 2016-05-30 20:48:23.000000000 +0300
 Birth: -
```

```
root# dived -J -u rust -g rust -- id
uid=1048(rust) gid=1057(rust) groups=1057(rust)
root# dived -J -u rust -g rust -- dd of=/home/vi/home/rust/myfile
dd: failed to open ‘/home/vi/home/rust/myfile’: Permission denied

root# dived -J -u rust -g 99999 -- id
uid=1048(rust) gid=99999 groups=99999
root# dived -J -u rust -g 99999 -- dd of=/home/vi/home/rust/myfile
sfdasafd
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
9 bytes (9 B) copied, 1.14971 s, 0.0 kB/s
```

A mystery. Can grsecurity patches be a problem?

---

Next experiment:

```
root# stat /home/vi/home/rust/myfile
  File: ‘/home/vi/home/rust/myfile’
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: fb02h/64258d    Inode: 13848412    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: (99997/ UNKNOWN)   Gid: (99998/ UNKNOWN)
Access: 2016-05-31 00:39:24.000000000 +0300
Modify: 2016-05-31 00:39:24.000000000 +0300
Change: 2016-05-31 00:39:24.000000000 +0300
 Birth: -
root# getfacl /home/vi/home/rust/myfile
getfacl: /home/vi/home/rust/myfile: Invalid argument
root# for i in {0..1099}; do if dived -J -u $i -g 99998 -- touch /home/vi/home/rust/myfile 2> /dev/null; then echo $i; fi; done
0
1000
root# 
root# 
root# mount -o remount,noacl /home
root# 
root# for i in {0..1099}; do if dived -J -u $i -g 99998 -- touch /home/vi/home/rust/myfile 2> /dev/null; then echo $i; fi; done | head
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
(and so on, basically it works)
root# mount -o remount,acl /home
root# 
root# for i in {0..1099}; do if dived -J -u $i -g 99998 -- touch /home/vi/home/rust/myfile 2> /dev/null; then echo $i; fi; done | head
0
1000
root#
```

Looks like `getfacl` (or it's kernel part) is a problem. ACLs are in effect, but are not manageable.

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/15042/117549

Comment: @JeffSchaller, It is not specific to `touch`. With `printf '' >> myfile` it is the same. I see `open("myfile", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)` in strace.

Comment: If `vi` can't write to a `rw-rw-rw-` file (no ACL) and a user who isn't either `vi` or the owner can write to the file, this can't be explained by usual Unix permissions. So yes, I'd lean towards some configuration of a security module. Have you checked logs?

Comment: No relevant logs (in grsecurity case it is dmesg). `vi`, as owner, can write to the file. The access disappears when group 1057 gets added to the process's group list. I've set file's ower to 99998 and tried looping over uids; it works in this mode only from uid=1000 and uid=0 (although I don't see 1000 in file's stat).

Comment: I tried moving the file to `/tmp/` and got `mv: getting attribute ‘system.posix_acl_access’ of ‘system.posix_acl_access’: Invalid argument`. Moved file works as it should. Maybe there is a problem with getfacl?...

Comment: `mount -o remount,noacl /home` turns off the mystery. `mount -o remount,acl /home` turns it on again. `getfacl` fails in both cases.

Comment: Doing reiserfsck, there is a lot of internal files like `/.reiserfs_priv/xattrs/5F05AC.180CCB4/system.posix_acl_access`.

Comment: What are the parent directory permissions? If the `rust` user doesn't have write access to the parent, it will have issues when trying to write to the directory and anything in it.

Comment: @ThomasN, It is basically this: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=197628

Answer (score 0):

The problem is ReiserFS being neglected in Linux: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=197628

> ACL is broken in reiserfs from Kernel 4.4.x  (Invalid argument error)
>   4.3.x worked fine for me...

I haven't checked yet how to goes in kernels after 4.4.

One need to reboot to a kernel <4.4 to be able to remove broken ACLs from the filesystem.